# An interesting Quaternary inequality

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, inequality

Let $a,b,c,d\in[-1,1]$ and assume $a^2+c^2\leq1, b^2+d^2\leq1$ (The original post does not have the inequality constraint which is wrong. Now all conditions reduce to the two inequality condition). Is the following inequality true?
$$(ac - bd)^2\leq\lambda\left[(a^2-b^2)^2+(c^2-d^2)^2\right]$$
for some $\lambda>0$? Specifically, is this inequality true for $\lambda=1$? What is the smallest $\lambda$ we can get to make this inequality true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such constant $\lambda > 0$. For  $c=d=\frac 12$ and $b=0$ the inequality reduces to
$$
 \frac 14 a^2 \le \lambda a^4
$$
which is wrong for $0 < a < \frac{1}{2\sqrt \lambda}$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot a condition...  $a^2+c^2\leq1, b^2+d^2\leq1$.

Comment: @neverevernever: Then choose $c = d = 1/2$.